# Fastercsv shows malformedCSVError, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastercsv

I am implementing in Ruby and i am running a project which reads a CSV file to add users.

but when i pick my file it just gives always the same error:

```
FasterCSV::MalformedCSVError in User importController#match

Illegal quoting on line 1.
```

my CSV file just exists of :

"RubenPersoon1","test","Bauwens","Ruben","rub@gmail.com",0

anyone who knows what can be wrong?

Comment: Are you _sure_ your CSV file looks like that? Might you have, say, two `'` where you think you have a single `"`?

Comment: Can you just try quoting that 0? I don't think that actually is the problem, but it won't hurt to rule that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upgrade your FasterCSV gem version. With the latest version it works:

```
FasterCSV.parse_line '"RubenPersoon1","test","Bauwens","Ruben","rub@gmail.com",0'
 => ["RubenPersoon1", "test", "Bauwens", "Ruben", "rub@gmail.com", "0"] 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :005 > FasterCSV.parse '"RubenPersoon1","test","Bauwens","Ruben","rub@gmail.com",0'
 => [["RubenPersoon1", "test", "Bauwens", "Ruben", "rub@gmail.com", "0"]]
```

Also, keep in mind that if you are on Ruby 1.9.2, `FasterCSV` is already included. Just `require 'csv'` and use the `CSV` class.